First load of page requires to put parameter in ASP.NET Core MVC using C#
I'm used to this set up:

Now, I'm doing my project in ASP.NET Core MVC with C#, I need to run the 1st page and make sure the URL is going to have a parameter which will be {ID}. I don't know how to do it in ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio 2022 since I'm not familiar with it. I actually don't know where the start action is. Can someone let me know on how to do this?
Looking for start action settings.




Right-click your MVC project, follow this direction, just fill in the URL, and close the dialog.

Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.
